# AnyLogic, Setting and updating a variable for each agents

Tags: anylogic

I am a new user of Anylogic but i have learned alot in the last few weeks, what i am trying to do is the following:

Imagine,I have a continuous rectangular conveyor on the Left & Right sides of the rectangular conveyor i have a picking station.

an agent named "BOX" is created at a rate of 5 / min, each box doesnt have to pass by all stations, Maybe station 1 only or maybe Station 2 only or maybe all two stations.

at a point on the bottom side of my rectangular conveyor i have an exit conveyor that should only pass Agents(Box) that have been completed ex( having variable = 9)

but when i created a parameter or variable i realized that it is shared by all the agents(Boxes) being created, how can i have a variable or parameter for each unit being produced of agent BOX.

please see the image below if it helps.

[image]

Comment: Please go through the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me where the parameter is located at the moment, but i guess that it is in the main object. 
if you want a parameter/variable for each agent. I'll suggest that you create it inside your BOX-agent. 
here you can find more information about agents and how to customise them: http://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/agentbased/Agent.html

When you test if the agent should exit, you can use: `agent.parameterName = 9` the "agent" part is a built-in function that will reference the agent currently in the object